# Send sprout email programmatically

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

I'm trying to send a sprout email from my plugin like so:

```php
use barrelstrength\sproutbaseemail\mailers\DefaultMailer;
use barrelstrength\sproutbaseemail\SproutBaseEmail;
use barrelstrength\sproutbaseemail\elements\NotificationEmail;

use Craft;
use craft\base\Plugin;

use yii\base\Event;

class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function init()
    {
        $mailer = SproutBaseEmail::$app->mailers->getMailerByName(DefaultMailer::class);

        // How do I let it know what email to send?
        $mailer->sendNotificationEmail();
    }
}
```

It says that `sendNotificationEmail` expects an instance of `NotificationEmail` but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to reference the notification email created on the dashboard so it can be sent.

The only similar question I found was [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/how-to-build-a-transactional-email-platform-with-craft) but it's for Craft2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the most simple level, if you have a Notification Email configured with the event 'None', you can do the following:

```php
$mailer = SproutBaseEmail::$app->mailers->getMailerByName(DefaultMailer::class);
$notificationEmail = Craft::$app->elements->getElementById(123);
$mailer->sendNotificationEmail($notificationEmail);
```

If you have an Event selected other than 'None' or want to use any Personalization in your email, you may need to also configure the notification to have the Event Object.

Let's say, your Notification Email body needs to use the person's name:

```
Hello {firstName}

OR

Hello {{ object.firstName }}
```

In that case, you can use the `setEventObject` method to set any variables you need available in your Email Template:

```php
$mailer = SproutBaseEmail::$app->mailers->getMailerByName(DefaultMailer::class);
$notificationEmail = Craft::$app->elements->getElementById(123);
$notificationEmail->setEventObject([
  'firstName' => 'Mr. Smithyyy'
]);
$mailer->sendNotificationEmail($notificationEmail);
```